# CanvasRenderingContext2D is faster when a path is rendered, instead of only a text

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Okay, so I am really scratching my head of what is happening here.

I have the following code running in a loop:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d") as CanvasRenderingContext2D;

let latestTime = performance.now();

function draw(time: number) {
  const dt = time - latestTime;
  const { width, height } = (document.getElementById(
    "main"
  ) as HTMLElement).getBoundingClientRect();

  if (canvas.width != width) canvas.width = width;
  if (canvas.height != height) canvas.height = height;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#333333";
  ctx.rect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.fill();


  /* When this section is commented out, the performance INCREASES...
  const size = 20;
  const radius = 100;
  const period = 10;

  const x =
    width / 2 + radius * Math.sin((((2 * Math.PI) / period) * time) / 1000);
  const y =
    height / 2 + radius * Math.cos((((2 * Math.PI) / period) * time) / 1000);

  ctx.fillStyle = "#9999ff";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.ellipse(x, y, size, size, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();*/

  ctx.font = "12px Montserrat";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
  ctx.fillText(`Frame rate: ${Math.round(1.0 / (dt / 1000))}`, 10, 20);

  latestTime = time;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw(performance.now());
```

It is a simple circle orbiting around the center when it is uncommented. However, I commented the circle part and only render the framerate.

When I run this and inspect in the Chrome Dev Tools the frame budget, I see this:
[image: System task takes up 7ms]

7ms is taken up by the system.
The framerate gradually goes down, but in steps. It is nicely 60. Then it goes to 30 all of a sudden after 30 seconds or so. Then it goes to 15. And so on.

When I uncomment the circle code the result in the inspector is this:

[image: System task takes up 0.67ms]

The system task only takes up 0.67ms and the framerate is constant.

I tried moving the section but it doesn't matter.

What is going on here? It doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `ctx.fillText` also does a  `ctx.beginPath` thus resetting any paths you have created.

The function `ctx.rect` add to the current path. Without the `beginPath` you are adding a rect to the current path each frame. Thus over time you are rendering more and more rectangles and thus the slow down.

Use `ctx.fillRect` rather than `ctx.rect` or start a new path with `ctx.beginPath` before the call to `ctx.rect`